# VS code does NOT show Flutter errors in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

For some reason, flutter in VS code stopped showing errors. No runtime or exception errors. Even when I put nulls everywhere on purpose, nothing shows in the console.

The red crash screen appears on device and emulators, but nothing with the details in console output. Not a single error. [This image is what I am talking about, it's gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkkkm.png)

Anybody ran into such a thing?
Thanks

Comment: How are you launching the app in VS Code?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny from the top menu bar:
Run => Run without debugging.

edit:
also Run ==> debugging and from terminal: `flutter run --release `

Comment: Running from the terminal won't write any output to the Debug Console, but it should write its output to the terminal too. Do you also not see the output written to the Terminal when running there with `flutter run`? Can you provide a code sample and a screenshot of the error on the device?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be using the `--release` flag - these errors will be hidden!

Comment: Problem was solved @NigelSheridan-Smith, and you are correct had that been the case, but it was a different reason. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another common cause of this, is using the filter box in debug console top right corner, if you typed something by mistake, it'll only show the words containing what you typed, and hide everything else. As mentioned by @jaredbaszler.

---

The code was passed down by another team mate, after inspecting the MyApp state, I found this in the initState, it was logging all error and not being shown in debug console.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocale();
    configLoading();
    FlutterError.onError = (details, {bool forceReport = false}) {
      sentry.captureException(
        exception: details.exception,
        stackTrace: details.stack,
      );
    };
  }
```

After removing it,I was happy to see the errors and exactly where they were happening. I discovered this a couple of months ago, and posted the answer in case anybody might run into it. Now it seems easy and makes sense, but I missed it.

Answer (score 30):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, I'll post my brain dead solution (insert face palm emoji).  I couldn't figure out what was going on for a good 2-3 hours as I was getting zero output in the `Debug Console` tab in the terminal window.  Turns out I had tried to filter the text using the filter text box.  Since nothing was matching my filter text, it was showing nothing.  Then I realized I had some text in the text box denoted below.  Hopefully this solution saves someone else from some head scratching.

[image]

Comment: Happens to the best, this is a very common cause and can easily be missed, I have added it to the answer as well. Thanks mate!

Comment: Faced the same exact thing but saw this correct answer after I figured it out. Glad I am not the only one

Comment: OMG cannot belive I did the same LOL