# Flutter errors not showing the debug console/terminal Vscode

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I purposely put errors in my Dart code to learn debugging, however the errors I put do not appear in the debug console nor using the terminal to start the app.
I am writing the code in Vscode

In my setState() i tried to pass an out of range index to see the error in the console, since I had already written a way so that the app would function normally when this happens, however the RangeError(index) is not showing in console, matter of fact is now showing anything apart from the start-up procedures.
My map `perguntas[]` has 3 valid indexes and in the setState() I use `_perguntaSelecionada` to pass the index I want to access , when I try to access index #10 it should throw a RangeError(index) in de debug console right?

```
  setState(() {
        _perguntaSelecionada+=10;
        _pontuacaoTotal += pontuacao;
      })
```

I even tried to force the access before the function that makes the app run normal by calling a print on the invalid index `print(_perguntas[_perguntaSelecionada]);`
However is not showing anything and I cannot get a grasp of what is happening.
I get no errors in `flutter doctor`

And using either of the commands

```
flutter run --release
or
flutter run
```

Does the same thing as in VSCode and shows nothing in debug terminal.
I already tried the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292489/vs-code-does-not-show-flutter-errors-in-debug-console) but none of them seemed to work for me

Comment: First don't use _flutter run --release_ it's not for debugging and second try using _log_ instead of _print_.

Comment: I don want to use log because my problem isn't with logging, if you read my quesiton is that the terminal is not outputing errors. I can se the errors if I try to log them.