# my VScode does NOT show Flutter errors in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My VSCode suddenly stop showing errors. The red crash screen appears on device and emulators, but nothing with the details in console output. Not a single error
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdfj2.jpg), [it's suppose to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pnd.jpg).

I've tried the solution in this page "[VS code does NOT show Flutter errors in debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292489/vs-code-does-not-show-flutter-errors-in-debug-console)"
but the problem still occur. Does anyone encounter this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

It shows the errors but in different colors. read the log!. based on the images you provided.